# Laravel/Ajax: refreshing the table stacks the new data at the bottom (old data stays)

Tags: sql, ajax, laravel, duplicates, crud

I am using `fetchcategory();` in order to refresh my table whenever I try to add, edit, and delete data. My issue is that everytime the table tries to reload, the newly update data stacks at the bottom of the table. Old information stays where they are. An example is shown below:

[image: 1]

My table has one existing record, the second screenshot shows the result after I add new data.

[image: 2]

As you can see, my else condition under `add_category` triggers. the very last line of code under the else is `fetchcategory();'. but the fetch simple adds the entire new table below the data before the update. This same goes for my edit and delete function.

My question is how come the table does not just reload the whole thing and take away the display of the old data?

Also, I want to refrain from using  `location.reload()` because I do not want the whole webpage to refresh, just the table.

**AJAX:**

```
 $(document).ready(function (){

        fetchcategory();

      function fetchcategory() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-data",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response){
                    $.each(response.all_categories, function (key, cat) {
                        $('tbody').append(`
                            <tr>
                                <td><p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">${cat.category_name}</p>${cat.category_description}</td>
                                <td>View:
                                    <mark class="mark-orange">${gettype(cat.config_view_type)}</mark>
                                    <br>Edit:
                                    <mark class="mark-orange">${gettype(cat.config_edit_type)}</mark>
                                </td>
                                <td>View:
                                    <mark class="mark-orange">${gettype(cat.bbrmode_view_type)}</mark>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" value="${cat.category_id}" class="edit_category btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
                                    <button type="button" value="${cat.category_id}" class="delete_category btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>`);
                    });

                    function gettype(type) {
                        var c_type = '';
                        if (type == 'P') {
                            c_type = 'Public'
                        } else if (type == 'R') {
                            c_type = 'Restricted'
                        } else if (type == undefined){
                            c_type = 'N/A'
                        }
                        return c_type;
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        $(document).on('click', '.delete_category', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //click this button(delete_category) to get the value(category_id)
            var cat_id = $(this).val(); 
            // alert(cat_id);
            $('#delete_cat_id').val(cat_id);
            $('#deleteCategoryModal').modal('show');
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.delete_category_btn', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var cat_id = $('#delete_cat_id').val();
            alert('Category Deleted!');
            $('#deleteCategoryModal').modal('hide'); 

            fetchcategory();

            //token taken from laravel documentation
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-delete/"+cat_id,
                dataType: "dataType",
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click','.edit_category',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var cat_id = $(this).val();
            console.log(cat_id);
            $('#editCategoryModal').modal('show');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-edit/"+cat_id,
                success: function (response) {
                     console.log(response);
                    if(response.status == 404) {
                        $('#success_message').html("");
                        $('#success_message').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                        $('#success_message').text(response.message);
                    } else {
                        $('#edit_category_name').val(response.category_edit.category_name);
                        $('#edit_category_description').val(response.category_edit.category_description);
                        $('#edit_cat_id').val(response.category_edit.category_id);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.update_category', function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var cat_id = $('#edit_cat_id').val();
            var update_data = {
                'category_name' : $('#edit_category_name').val(),
                'category_description' : $('#edit_category_description').val(),
            }

            //token taken from laravel documentation
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-update/"+cat_id,
                data: update_data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response){
                    // console.log(response);
                    if(response.status == 400) {
                        $('#category_formCheckUpdate').html("");
                        $('#category_formCheckUpdate').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                        $.each(response.errors, function (key, err_values) {
                            $('#category_formCheckUpdate').append('<li>'+err_values+'</li>');
                        });
                    } else if(response.status == 404) {
                        $('#category_formCheckUpdate').html("");
                        $('#category_notif').addClass('alert alert-success');
                        $('#category_notif').text(response.message);
                    } else {
                        $('#category_formCheckUpdate').html("");
                        $('#category_notif').html("");
                        $('#category_notif').addClass('alert alert-success');
                        $('#category_notif').text(response.message);
                        $('#editCategoryModal').modal('hide');
                        fetchcategory();
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.add_category', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var category_data = {
                'category_name': $('.category_name').val(),
                'category_description': $('.category_description').val(),
                'category_description': $('.category_description').val(),
                'config_view_type': $('.config_view_type').val(),
                'config_edit_type': $('.config_edit_type').val(),
                'bbrmode_view_type': $('.bbrmode_view_type').val(),
            }
            
            //token taken from laravel documentation
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration",
                data: category_data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response){
                    console.log(response);
                if(response.status == 400) {
                    $('#category_formCheck').html("");
                    $('#category_formCheck').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                    $.each(response.errors, function (key, err_values) {
                        $('#category_formCheck').append('<li>'+err_values+'</li>');
                    });
                    }
                else  
                  {
                    $('#category_notif').html("");
                    $('#category_notif').addClass('alert alert-success');
                    $('#category_notif').text(response.message);
                    $('#createCategory').modal('hide');
                    fetchcategory();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: can you code of fetchcategory()

Comment: @JohnLobo added

Comment: Hi, simply empty your tbody . Just add `$('tbody').empty()` before your each loop .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid appending at the bottom using `$('tbody').html()` instead of  `$('tbody').append(` so

```
function fetchcategory() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-data",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response){
                var tbody="";
                $.each(response.all_categories, function (key, cat) {
                   tbody+=`
                            <tr>
                                <td><p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">${cat.category_name}</p>${cat.category_description}</td>
                                <td>View:
                                    <mark class="mark-orange">${gettype(cat.config_view_type)}</mark>
                                    <br>Edit:
                                    <mark class="mark-orange">${gettype(cat.config_edit_type)}</mark>
                                </td>
                                <td>View:
                                    <mark class="mark-orange">${gettype(cat.bbrmode_view_type)}</mark>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" value="${cat.category_id}" class="edit_category btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
                                    <button type="button" value="${cat.category_id}" class="delete_category btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>`;
                });

                $('tbody').html(tbody)
                    function gettype(type) {
                    var c_type = '';
                    if (type == 'P') {
                        c_type = 'Public'
                    } else if (type == 'R') {
                        c_type = 'Restricted'
                    } else if (type == undefined){
                        c_type = 'N/A'
                    }
                    return c_type;
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: ah i see, looks like its only because of append. thanks for giving yet another valuable info/teaching!

Comment: @STGSH. even swati suggestion with  $('tbody').empty() before each also work well